# Identify duplicate Titles and/or URLs stored in MySQL (RSS articles)

Tags: php, mysql, rss

I am collecting articles from numerous RSS feeds into a MySQL database (just the title and link from the actual feed), and I would like to make sure I do not enter the same article twice when rechecking the feeds.  I anticipate storing up to 200,000 entries in the table.

Which would be the best way to check for duplicates:

1. Make the URL a unique field in the DB,
2. Create a new unique identifier for every article (like SHA1 the URL and/or title),
3. something else?

Edit: Thanks everyone for confirming #1.

Comment: I would do #1. clean and  fast.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`UNIQUE` keys are designed for this.

If you want to bulk insert but may have duplicate errors, use `INSERT IGNORE`

Comment: After deciding towards the `UNIQUE` approach you may want to use error checking to see if the item was inserted or not. Or if you do not care about that `INSERT IGNORE` is indeed the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

Of your 3 options, **1** is the only feasable one without doing *extra* work.

Options 2 & 3 all require doing *more*.  Stick to `UNIQUE` INSERTS.